# Power BI Multi Tenant - Oauth2

Tags: sharepoint, oauth-2.0, powerbi

I am trying to connect to a SharePoint folder, located in a external tenant.

(My Main tenant has a guest account on this external tenant)

This uses OAuth2 authentication.

Works fine on PBI Desktop but not in Power BI Service.

I have seen that Microsoft have stated the following ;

"If you want to connect to a data source from Power BI service by using OAuth2, the data source must be in the same tenant as the Power BI service. Currently, multi-tenant connection scenarios aren't supported with OAuth2."

Are there any workarounds for this ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Microsoft has stated that multi-tenant connection scenarios aren't supported with OAuth2. And, there are no known workarounds for this limitation at this time.